# Prove $x_1$ is at least a $k$-fold root of polynomial $p$ if and only if $p(x_1) = p^{'}(x_1) = \dots p^{(k-1)}(x_1) = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Suppose $p: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a polynomial given by $x \mapsto a_nx^n + \dots a_1 x_1 + a_0$.

How do I prove $x_1$ is at least a $k$-fold root of $p$ if and only if $p(x_1) = p^{'}(x_1) = \dots p^{(k-1)}(x_1) = 0$ ?

I guess it is understood $k \le n$.

I see that if $x_1$ is a $k$-fold root of $p$ we can write $p(x) = (x-x_1)^ks(x)$ and I immediately see that $p(x_1) = p^{'}(x_1) = \dots p^{(k-1)}(x_1) = 0$ by taking the derivative succesively.

How is the other way proved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First since $x_1$ is a root we can write $p(x)=(x-x_1)q(x)$. Now differentiating this we observe that $$p'(x)=(x-x_1)q'(x)+q(x)$$ But $p'(x_1)=0$ implies that $q(x_1)=0$. Proceeding like this by n times and you can complete the proof.

Comment: So we do induction up to $n$ the degree of $p(x)$ and stops there, right ?

Comment: @user111854 yes because if it did not stop there then $p^{(n+1)}(x_1)=0$.

Comment: But why does this imply $x_1$ is a $k$-multiple root ?

Comment: @user111854 in the answer  I showed that if the function and the derivative are zero at a point then it is a 2 multiple root. Now assume that it is k-1 multiple root. Then differentiate $(x-x_1)^{k-1}h(x)$ k times and note that for the hypothesis to be true $h(x_1)=0$

Comment: But if $x_1$ is a root of $p^{'}(x)$ why is it then a multiple root of $p(x)$ ?

Comment: if $x_1$ is a root of $p'(x)$ then I showed that it is a root of $q(x)$ which means it is a 2 multiple root of $p(x)$. I hope this helps

Comment: Aha ! Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are welcome :)